# Override WordPress plugin class to change upload image size

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to change the function inside the handler class for uploading user image from front end using the the code which mostly works in situations like this one:

```
class Custom_Class extends Main_Class {
  function __construct() {
    remove_action('default_action', array($this));
    add_action('new_action', array($this));
  }
  /* custom code from here on */
}
new Custom_Class
```

The goal is to change the `$image->resize` value to 320px, but I can not even remove the action, and the original code looks like this:

```
class UR_Form_Handler {
/**
 * Hook in methods.
 */
public static function init() {
    add_action( 'template_redirect', array( __CLASS__, 'redirect_reset_password_link' ) );
    add_action( 'template_redirect', array( __CLASS__, 'save_profile_details' ) );
    add_action( 'template_redirect', array( __CLASS__, 'save_change_password' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( __CLASS__, 'process_login' ), 20 );
    add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( __CLASS__, 'process_lost_password' ), 20 );
    add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( __CLASS__, 'process_reset_password' ), 20 );
    add_action( 'user_registration_before_customer_login_form', array( __CLASS__, 'export_confirmation_request' ) );
}

/**
 * Save/update a profile fields if the form was submitted through the user account page.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function save_profile_details() {
    if ( 'POST' !== strtoupper( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( empty( $_POST['action'] ) || 'save_profile_details' !== $_POST['action'] || empty( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'save_profile_details' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if ( $user_id <= 0 ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( has_action( 'uraf_profile_picture_buttons' ) ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['profile_pic_url'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['profile_pic_url'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_registration_profile_pic_url', $_POST['profile_pic_url'] );
        }
    } else {
        if ( isset( $_FILES['profile-pic'] ) && $_FILES['profile-pic']['size'] ) {

            if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
                require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
            }

            $upload           = $_FILES['profile-pic'];
            $upload_overrides = array(
                'action' => 'save_profile_details',
            );
            $uploaded         = wp_handle_upload( $upload, $upload_overrides );

            if ( $uploaded && ! isset( $uploaded['error'] ) ) {
                $image = wp_get_image_editor( $uploaded['file'] );

                if ( ! is_wp_error( $image ) ) {
                    $image->resize( 150, 150, true );
                    $image->save( $uploaded['file'] );
                }
                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_registration_profile_pic_url', $uploaded['url'] );
            } else {
                ur_add_notice( $uploaded['error'], 'error' );
            }
        } elseif ( UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE !== $_FILES['profile-pic']['error'] ) {

            switch ( $_FILES['profile-pic']['error'] ) {
                case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                    ur_add_notice( __( 'File size exceed, please check your file size.', 'user-registration' ), 'error' );
                    break;
                default:
                    ur_add_notice( __( 'Something went wrong while uploading, please contact your site administrator.', 'user-registration' ), 'error' );
                    break;
            }
        } elseif ( empty( $_POST['profile-pic-url'] ) ) {
            $upload_dir  = wp_upload_dir();
            $profile_url = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_registration_profile_pic_url', true );

            // Check if profile already set?
            if ( $profile_url ) {

                // Then delete file and user meta.
                $profile_url = $upload_dir['basedir'] . explode( '/uploads', $profile_url )[1];

                if ( ! empty( $profile_url ) && file_exists( $profile_url ) ) {
                    @unlink( $profile_url );
                }
                delete_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_registration_profile_pic_url' );
            }
        }
    }

    $form_id_array = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'ur_form_id' );
    $form_id       = 0;

    if ( isset( $form_id_array[0] ) ) {
        $form_id = $form_id_array[0];
    }

    $profile = user_registration_form_data( $user_id, $form_id );

    foreach ( $profile as $key => $field ) {
        if ( ! isset( $field['type'] ) ) {
            $field['type'] = 'text';
        }
        // Get Value.
        switch ( $field['type'] ) {
            case 'checkbox':
                if ( isset( $_POST[ $key ] ) && is_array( $_POST[ $key ] ) ) {
                    $_POST[ $key ] = $_POST[ $key ];
                } else {
                    $_POST[ $key ] = (int) isset( $_POST[ $key ] );
                }
                break;
            default:
                $_POST[ $key ] = isset( $_POST[ $key ] ) ? ur_clean( $_POST[ $key ] ) : '';
                break;
        }

        // Hook to allow modification of value.
        $_POST[ $key ] = apply_filters( 'user_registration_process_myaccount_field_' . $key, $_POST[ $key ] );

        $disabled = false;
        if ( isset( $field['custom_attributes'] ) && isset( $field['custom_attributes']['readonly'] ) && isset( $field['custom_attributes']['disabled'] ) ) {
            if ( 'readonly' === $field['custom_attributes']['readonly'] || 'disabled' === $field['custom_attributes']['disabled'] ) {
                $disabled = true;
            }
        }

        if ( ! empty( $_POST[ $key ] ) ) {

            // Validation rules.
            if ( ! empty( $field['validate'] ) && is_array( $field['validate'] ) ) {
                foreach ( $field['validate'] as $rule ) {
                    switch ( $rule ) {
                        case 'email':
                            $_POST[ $key ] = strtolower( $_POST[ $key ] );

                            if ( ! is_email( $_POST[ $key ] ) ) {
                                ur_add_notice( sprintf( __( '%s is not a valid email address.', 'user-registration' ), '<strong>' . $field['label'] . '</strong>' ), 'error' );
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }// End foreach().

    do_action( 'user_registration_after_save_profile_validation', $user_id, $profile );

    if ( 0 === ur_notice_count( 'error' ) ) {
        $user_data = array();

        foreach ( $profile as $key => $field ) {
            $new_key = str_replace( 'user_registration_', '', $key );

            if ( in_array( $new_key, ur_get_user_table_fields() ) ) {

                if ( $new_key === 'display_name' ) {
                    $user_data['display_name'] = $_POST[ $key ];
                } else {
                    $user_data[ $new_key ] = $_POST[ $key ];
                }
            } else {
                $update_key = $key;

                if ( in_array( $new_key, ur_get_registered_user_meta_fields() ) ) {
                    $update_key = str_replace( 'user_', '', $new_key );
                }
                $disabled = isset( $field['custom_attributes']['disabled'] ) ? $field['custom_attributes']['disabled'] : '';

                if ( $disabled !== 'disabled' ) {
                    update_user_meta( $user_id, $update_key, $_POST[ $key ] );
                }
            }
        }

        if ( count( $user_data ) > 0 ) {
            $user_data['ID'] = get_current_user_id();
            wp_update_user( $user_data );
        }

        do_action( 'user_registration_save_profile_details', $user_id, $form_id );

        wp_safe_redirect( ur_get_endpoint_url( 'edit-profile', '', ur_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) );
        exit;
    }
  }
}
```

Either I get Fatal error: Cannot make static method UR_Form_Handler::save_profile_details() non static in class Custom_UR_Form_Handler, or the override doesn't work at all, I'm not sure if I'm even doing this the right way, maybe there's no need to override the entire function, but I'm stuck with this, any help or idea would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is this plugin ?. Maybe you can ask the plugin author to add a specific filter here.

Comment: It's User Registration plugin - https://wpeverest.com/wordpress-plugins/user-registration/